# modern physics :emission spectrum

Tags: homework-and-exercises, energy, atomic-physics, hydrogen

If in a hydrogen atom all possible transactions take place. The ratio of maximum frequency to minimum frequency is 135/7.what is the principal quantum number of excited state.
The max frequency case will be from n to 1 where n is the principal quantum number of excited state,but what will be the min frequency case how to prove that it will be from 2 to 1??

Answer (score 1):

> but what will be the min frequency case how to prove that it will be from 2 to 1??

The minimum frequency case will **not** be a transition from n=2 to n=1.

I'm not giving a final answer since this is a homework-type question.